Playstore is rejecting my app due to Full-screen intent permission
In our react-native app, Google Play says "Remove Full-screen intent permission or submit declaration", so I checked my AndroidManifest.xml, but there was no  USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission, upon further inspection, I found out that we are using @notifee/react-native which is using USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission, but in our app we are not showing full screen notification in any case. So, I removed the permission manually from AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" tools:node="remove" />
    ...
</manifest>

and my android/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-release-report.txt shows that the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT is REJECTED

But still google play shows 1 declaration needs attention error and not allowing me to upload newer versions.

EDIT:
The issue seems to with Play Store. The message on the Play Store is super confusing. If I click into it, I see that the declaration is for existing bundles, not the new bundle I am trying to upload. However, I can't proceed with the new upload until the declaration is made.

What happens when you use the "start decleration" button?

It asks me "What is the core functionality of your app?" and gives me option of

Alarm clock
Making and receiving calls
Others


But my app is not triggering alarms nor making or receiving calls, but I am confused regarding why should I submit declaration form as I already removed that permission manually.

I understand, I was just wondering because your screenshot states "fix any issues and complete the declaration"

But in below lines it is written  Remove Full-screen intent permission or submit declaration..
I highlighted the text in screen shot

Maybe someone else knows what to do

I have the same problem here and updates

Does that mean the app should be one of these [1. Alarm clock 2. Making and receiving calls]
or request permission from the user?

This is due to Notifee auto-adding permissions.
Please try the following:
In your AndroidManifest.xml, that's ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ### ADD THIS STATEMENT>
// some content ...

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" tools:node="remove" /> ### ADD THIS STATEMENT (I added it as the last permission statement)

I use in some of my apps Notifiee too and it removed the permission from the final build. Play Store accepted a new version of my app without any declaration needed.
It might affect some other modules not only Notifee.

I have already added these lines in  AndroidManifest.xml, the problem seems to be with play store. The message on the Play Store is super confusing. If I click into it, I see that the declaration is for existing bundles, not the new bundle I am trying to upload. However, I can't proceed with the new upload until the declaration is made.

It seems like there are new Google Play policies in place.

I submitted a new version without this permission together with filled in form for the last version on Google Play and it was accepted just fine.

Where can I check this on my play console? and how did you make this form @gtom

This solved the problem for me. I was seeing it as a declaration that needed attention, but it's not there any more. Didn't do anything extra in Play Store.

I was having the same issue after adding the change outlined in the answer. I cleared the error by deleting the pending release from Google Play and redeploying. Now I'm able to publish again from my build server without manual intervention and with USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT removed.

To anyone not clear on this, it took me a while to understand what was going on.
If you're getting this error, it means that Google Play has a build of your app that has the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission set inside it.
You will be unable to upload any new builds, because Google wants you to submit a USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT declaration on the App Content page for how you're using this permission, but there's no option to say "i'm not using this". You're now stuck in a weird state.
Here's the solution:
To remove this warning, you will need to archive all builds of your app that have this permission. Until you do this, you will be blocked in this state.
You can check which permissions are on each build in the App bundle explorer page, and if any of your releases (internal, closed, production) use this bundle, you will have to create a new release with a different bundle.
Once you have archived all bundles with that permission, you can upload new versions of your app to Google Play. You will have to make sure that the new bundle you're uploading doesn't have the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission.
Hopefully this all makes sense.

The issue is because of using older versions of Notifee in React Native. You can upgrade notifee to version > 9.0.0 and the issue is gone or remove the permission from your app.
In your main manifest file here: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" tools:node="remove"/>

Important Note:
Even after fixing it Google might show you the error because it's showing the error for previous releases (internal or testing included) so you might need to upload the new version in internal or testing too. After that you can go to the production track and continue with the release.
If you are not sure which release it
