Android Full Screen Intent Compliance
Problem: Our app, which includes essential video conferencing functionality, has been rejected by Google Play due to the use of the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission. Google claims this permission is not related to our app’s core purpose... even though it is.  We display the notifications for video conferencing which is a core feature of the app. We've appealed their decision that its not a core feature numerous times but can't get a straight answer out of them. I'm wondering, if we are forced to remove the permission pre-granted at installation, it seems like we'll need to have the user grant permission for the notification but the documentation is sending some mixed messages.
Conflicting Documentation:

Google documentation indicates that apps with calling functionalities can use USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT (but then they reject the app saying its not a core feature)
The rejection notice instructs us to remove this permission - but if we remove it from the AndroidManfiest.xml will we still be able to show a full screen intent later if they grant hte "special permissions"?


Remove the use of USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission from all version codes within the submission. This includes both production and testing tracks.


Documentation reference: "Upon installation, the Google Play Store revokes the full-screen intent (FSI) permission for apps that do not have calling or alarm functionalities."

Again - our app does have a calling feature



I'm just looking for guidance on if we need to "Remove the use of USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission from all version codes within the submission" what do we need to do to make this compliant and still work as we need?
Thanks for your help!


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78569030/playstore-is-rejecting-my-app-due-to-full-screen-intent-permission

I have the same warning 2 days ago. I create alarm app. But google Play consider my app core function is not alarm and prohibit the use full screen intent. Google Play advise me to delete full screen intent permission. But i think it will make my alarm notification not showing at idle and my app will lost against competitor. I think it is not fair. .. After checking on another alarm app, I found out that my full screen intent keep displaying forever when the user has no reaction to the full screen intent. I fix it by closing the full screen intent automatically when the times has elapsed for a one or few minutes.

interesting! I might be doing that too.
I was eventually able to fix my issue by sending the appeals team a video of the app using the call feature and they accepted the appeal and let me keep the intent
